# ANDROID GC_FOR_ALLOC freed in my app going wrong

Tags: java, android, file

That's my android code which takes 30 min to copy a 3MB `.log` file into a `.zip` and gives lots of `GC_FOR_ALLOC`. I also tried to change buffersize from `1k` to `8k`

```
File tempFolder=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY_TEMP); 
String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY_TEMP+ "/";
String fileName ="";
String zipFileName="";

String date=DATE_FORMAT_TEMP.format(new Date());
fileName = Settings.LOG_FILE_PREFIX + date+"_" + IMEI +.log; 
zipFileName = Settings.LOG_FILE_PREFIX + date+"_" + IMEI +.zip;

br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
String result="";
String line = "";
while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
    result += line;

result = getHeader() + result;
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(result.getBytes());

File zipFile=new File(filePath+zipFileName);

iStream = new FileInputStream(file);
oStream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);

zos = new ZipOutputStream(oStream);
ze = new ZipEntry(fileName);
zos.putNextEntry(ze);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while((length = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
zos.flush();
oStream.flush();
```

Comment: br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
       
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            result += line;
i have problem in these line of code which take much time

Answer (score 0):

In your code it looks like you are opening and reading the file twice (your `BufferedReader` and your iStream object). Also, you are loading the entire file into memory twice before writing anything to memory. That's still only 6MB but you probably are hitting your memory stack limit - unless you use `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest.

Before you do that though, try just reading/writing each part:

```
    public void zip(String[] _files, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFileName);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

            for (int i = 0; i < _files.length; i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]);
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]);
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the reference: http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-programmatically-zip-and-unzip-file-in-android